# Django Shell image upload _io.BufferedReader no attribute size

Tags: python, django, shell

My problem is that when I try to save image to my model using Django shell I get this error that I can't find solution anywere.

models.py

```
class AdImage(models.Model):
   ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad)
   full_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True)
```

I import models create AdImage instance add 'ad' and try to

```
imagead.full_photo.save("NowHiring.jpg",open("C:\\NowHiring.jpg", "rb"))
```

but i get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\hp\Envs\platform\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\file
s.py", line 106, in save
    self._size = content.size
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Using: **Python 3.5, Django 1.9**

What could I do ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `FieldFile.save` method needs to be called with an instance of `django.core.files.File`, rather than a built-in python file handle.  Change the save invocation to:

```py
from django.core.files import File

imagead.full_photo.save("NowHiring.jpg", File(open("C:\\NowHiring.jpg", "rb")))
```

Django docs reference for [`FieldFile.save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save).